# The probability that a randomly selected integer is squarefree

Tags: number-theory, riemann-zeta

What does

> the probability that a randomly selected integer is squarefree

mean (in [this context](http://oeis.org/A059956))?

Comment: It is similar to the explanation [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function#Euler_product_formula). It is an asymptotic probability, e.g. you consider the probability that a randomly selected integer from $\{-n,-(n-1),\ldots,0,1,\ldots,n\}$ is squarefree, and then take $n \to \infty$.

Comment: See also [Coprimality and squarefree numbers](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/34971/coprimality-and-squarefree-numbers/34975).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means this:

Let $n$ be a positive integer, and define $s_n$ to be the number of square-free integers between $1$ and $n$ inclusive. Then
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{s_n}{n} = \frac{6}{\pi^2}$$

(Equivalently, you can allow negative integers, and define $t_n$ to be the number of square-free integers between $-n$ and $n$ inclusive. Then $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{t_n}{2n}= \frac{6}{\pi^2}$.)

Comment: I see. And in the case of "two randomly selected integers", I suppose you select them from the same interval $[1,n]$.

Comment: @user66081: Yes.

Answer (score 1):

Tony already explained the meaning... you take the "frequency" ("probability") of something happening on $[1,n]$, and then you take the limit as $n \to \infty$. This is not a *probability* in the sense of probability theory. There is no probability measure on a $\sigma$ - algebra on $\Bbb Z$ or $\Bbb N$ under which this number is the "probability" of an event. In fact no such probability space can exist. It is an unfortunate (confusing) abuse of terminology.

It is the same sense in which the "probability" of a randomly chosen integer being even (or odd) is 0.5.